# Are there alternatives to FileDataModel?

Tags: java, parsing, hadoop, mahout, bigdata

I'm new to mahout and this field of big data.
In general data doesn't come as a (long, long, Double) all the time.
So are there alternatives to FileDataModel?

```
DataModel model = new FileDataModel(new File("Ratings.csv"));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Users and items are identified solely by an ID value in the framework.
>   Further, this ID value must be numeric; it is a Java long type through
>   the APIs. A Preference object or PreferenceArray object encapsulates
>   the relation between user and preferred items (or items and users
>   preferring them).

I have recently faced the same issue. I had user id UUID type. But I had to add additional table with numeric user id and original UUID user id. Later checking the documentation i have found this explanation. According other implementation of **DataModel** :

> A DataModel is the interface to information about user preferences. An
>   implementation might draw this data from any source, but a database is
>   the most likely source. Be sure to wrap this with a
>   ReloadFromJDBCDataModel to get good performance! Mahout provides
>   MySQLJDBCDataModel, for example, to access preference data from a
>   database via JDBC and MySQL. Another exists for PostgreSQL. Mahout
>   also provides a FileDataModel, which is fine for small applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can build DataModel from Database. 
Here is a example for PostgreSQL:

Intercafe looks like this:

```
PostgreSQLJDBCDataModel(DataSource dataSource, String preferenceTable, String userIDColumn, String itemIDColumn, String preferenceColumn, String timestampColumn)
```

Initalization:

```
source = new PGPoolingDataSource();
source.setDataSourceName(properties.getProperty("DATABASE_NAME"));
source.setServerName("127.0.0.1");
source.setDatabaseName(properties.getProperty("DATABASE_NAME"));
source.setUser(properties.getProperty("DATABASE_USER"));
source.setPassword(properties.getProperty("DATABASE_PASS"));
source.setMaxConnections(50);

DataModel model =new  PostgreSQLJDBCDataModel(
                            source,
                            "mahout_teble",
                            "user_id",
                            "item_id",
                            "preference",
                            "timestamp"
                            )
                    )
```